# Can I use the Mending cantrip to repair a Broken Firearm?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, firearms

I have a character with the Mending cantrip, and a firearm.

On the [Firearms](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons/firearms) page, I read that "When a firearm misfires, it gains the broken condition."

However, [Mending](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/m/mending) reads: "If the object has the broken condition, this condition is removed if the object is restored to at least half its original hit points."

RAW, I take it that Mending cannot remove the Broken condition from a firearm, because I am not restoring it to half it's original hit points, because misfires do not cause damage to weapon. If my weapon did misfire, I would... have to damage it to cast Mending to restore it. This seems silly.

[Make Whole](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/m/make-whole) "functions as mending, except that it repairs 1d6 points of damage per level", so has the same limitations.

The Gunslinger's [Quick Clear](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/gunslinger#TOC-Deeds) deed specifically doesn't restore HP but removes Broken anyway.

Am I missing something, here? To use Mending to fix a gun, do I have to damage the gun first, RAW?

Answer (score 11):

I understand the broken condition removal of Mending as

> If the target has at least half of its original HP at the end of Mending, then Broken is removed.

If you use Mending or Make Whole on a full HP firearm, it will have been restored to "at least half its original hit points" (from full HP to full HP) and will be unbroken.